# Show that $\| v\|_{L^2(0,b)}=o(\| u\|_{L^2(0,b)})$ as $b \to \infty$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, asymptotics

Let $\alpha<0$ and let $u(x):= e^{\alpha x}$ for $x \geq 0$. I'm reading a paper which states that there are constants  $d_{j}, \beta_{j} \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\beta_j>0$ such that if we define
$$v(x) =\sum_{j=1}^n d_{j} e^{ \beta_{j} (x-b)}$$
then $w^{(j)}(b)=0$ for $j=0,1, \ldots, n-1$ if $w(x):=v(x)+u(x)$, and
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\| v\|_{L^2(0,b)}=o(\| u\|_{L^2(0,b)}) \ \ \ \mbox{as} \ \ b \to \infty
\end{equation}

I think that the constants $d_j$ depend on $b$. I am struggling to prove (1).

**My attempt**

I tried the following:
$$\|v\|_{L^2(0,b)}^2 \leq n M_b \int_{[0,b]} \sum_{j=1}^n e^{2 \beta_{j}(x-b)}= nM_b \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1-e^{-2 \beta_{j}b}}{2 \beta_{j}},$$
where $M_b:=\max\{|d_{j,b}|^2: j=1, \ldots,n\}$. But using that $\|u \|^2_{L^2(0,b)}=(e^{\alpha b}-1)/\alpha$ I can not get (1).

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: This does not seem to be true for $n = 1$: $w(b) = w'(b) = 0$ implies that $\beta_1 < 0$...

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki It was a typo. I only want $w^{(j)}(b)=0$ for $j=0,1,\ldots,n-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly the question, but this is too long for a comment.

Fix $\alpha < 0$ and take any distinct $\beta_j > 0$, $j = 1, 2, \ldots n$. Then there is a unique solution $d_j$, $j = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, of the system of linear equations $$ \frac{d^i}{dx^i} \bigg|_{x = 0} \biggl(\sum_{j = 1}^n d_j e^{\beta_j x}\biggr) = -\alpha^i , \qquad i = 0, 1, \ldots, n - 1.$$ For $b > 0$ define $$ v(x) = \sum_{j = 1}^n d_j e^{\beta_j (x - b) + \alpha b} $$ (note the additional factor $e^{\alpha b}$!). Then $w(x) = v(x) + e^{\alpha x}$ has derivatives of order $0, 1, \ldots, n - 1$ at $x = b$ all equal to zero, as desired. Furthermore, the $L^2$ norm of $e^{\alpha x}$ on $(0, b)$ converges to a constant as $b \to \infty$, while the $L^2$ norm of $v$ on $(0, b)$ decays as $e^{\alpha b}$ as $b \to \infty$.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: It works better than the function given on the paper. Thank you very much!.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Why is there a unique solution of the linear system?

Comment: @Mainkit: The coefficients form a Vandermonde matrix, I suppose.